# If $\sum a_n$ converges and for almost all n $a_n>0$, does it mean that the series $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If $\sum a_n$ converges and for almost all n $a_n>0$,
does it mean that the series $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely ?

Thanks.

Comment: If 'almost all' means that the number of negative $a_n$ is finite then the answer is 'yes'. It is allready sufficient to have $a_n\geq 0$ (a bit weaker). The summation of negatives will be a negative number and not someting like $-\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If 'almost all' means that the  $F:=\{n\mid a_n<0\}$  is finite then the answer is 'yes'.

It is allready sufficient to have $a_n ≥0$  for almost all $n$ (a bit weaker).

The summation of negatives will be a negative number (or $0$ if there are no negatives) and not someting like $-\infty$, so:

$$\sum\left|a_{n}\right|=\sum_{n\in F^{c}}a_{n}-\sum_{n\in F}a_{n}<\infty$$